# When will the EIP 2 fork kick in?

Tags: forks, homestead, hardforks, eip

[EIP 2](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.mediawiki) is a fork cleaning the protocol a little. When will the fork kick in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the document you will find the answer.

> If block.number >= HOMESTEAD_FORK_BLKNUM (eg. 100,000,000 (NOT YET SET IN STONE!) on livenet and Morden

At this moment it's simply not decided yet.

**Edit, this has been confirmed now.**

> The Homestead block will be 1.150.000 for the main network which means the Homestead transition will be roughly around midday on Pi day and the Homestead block for the Morden network will be 494.000.

Answer (score 10):

> The Homestead block will be 1.150.000 for the main network which means
>   the Homestead transition will be roughly around midday on Pi day and
>   the Homestead block for the Morden network will be 494.000.

[Source](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/02/29/homestead-release/)

Comment: I am so confused EIP 2 is marked as accepted, but you all say that it already happen? Then it must be final! 
Why is EIP 2 the same day as homestead? Is it not some times after Hom 
I am so confused EIP 2 is marked as accepted, but you all say that it already happen? Then it must be final! Why is EIP 2 the same day as homestead? Is it not some times after Homestead? Gran' Casino! –estead? Gran' Casino! maybe you or @5chdn could change the answer to reflect the true state of the things

Answer (score 3):

1. **EIP2 will be [released on Pi Day](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/02/29/homestead-release/) (Mar 14, 2016) at block 1,150,000.**
2. There is already the homestead [website prototype available for testing](http://dipl.me:3000/).

   [image: homepage preivew]
3. On reddit there is a [call for updating the documentation](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/42vuik/homestead_documentation_initiative/) for homestead.
4. In the devcon1 keynote [Vitalik Buterin said](https://youtu.be/BUARih8_f68?t=3m36s) homestead is to be expected when the ethereum network, miners and other critical components work without serious hiccups for about 4 weeks.
5. <del>The recent [go ethereum homestead release candidate](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2258) suggests [block number 2,000,000](https://github.com/obscuren/go-ethereum/blob/1d2b26f18c6f344ce9a0a2d0cc51b977fb295aa4/params/util.go#L21), but also states the block number is not final.</del>

Comment: It's 2m just so we don't accidentally hit it while the PR is merged in to `develop`. Accidental release of homestead would suck big time ;-)